# Using Node JS to Tunnel sub directory as localhost with Port 3000

Tags: node.js, ngrok

I am using the following code to tunnel a sub directory login page into localhost with port 3000. I am doing this so that when I use ngrok, I would be able to directly open the below link instead of having to type /mooshak/ after the ngrok link.

Main goal is to have

http://127.0.0.1:8180/mooshak/Authentication.html?locale=en#login

to be replaced by

http://127.0.0.1:3000/

When I use the below code, instead of 127.0.0.1:3000 showing the login page, I still have to use the same link as above, replacing 8180 by 3000 as the port number. How do I make sure that 
http://127.0.0.1:3000/
points to 
http://127.0.0.1:8180/mooshak/Authentication.html?locale=en#login ?

```
var app = require('express')();
//fix ssl localhost
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";

app.use('/', proxy('http://127.0.0.1:8180/mooshak/Authentication.html?locale=en#login'));
app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Have you tried to change nginx or apache locations?

Comment: @Puriajahanbani I have no idea regarding apache locations for the same since I'm new at this. Could you please provide me any guide to perform the exact same thing?